# Sybase sybpydb queries not returning anything

Tags: python, sql, sap-ase

I am currently connecting to a Sybase 15.7 server using [sybpydb](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01692.1570/doc/html/car1308847098623.html). It seems to connect fine:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/dba/sybase/ase/15.7/OCS-15_0/python/python26_64r/lib')
sys.path.append('/dba/sybase/ase/15.7/OCS-15_0/lib')
import sybpydb

conn = sybpydb.connect(user='usr', password='pass', servername='serv')
```

is working fine. Changing any of my connection details results in a connection error.

I then select a database:

```
curr = conn.cursor()
curr.execute('use db_1')
```

however, now when I try to run queries, it always returns `None`

```
print curr.execute('select * from table_1')
```

I have tried running the `use` and `select` queries in the same `execute`, I have tried including `go` commands after each, I have tried using `curr.connection.commit()` after each, all with no success. I have confirmed, using `dbartisan` and `isql`, that the same queries I am using return entries.

Why am I not getting results from my queries in python?

EDIT:

Just some additional info. In order to get the `sybpydb` import to work, I had to change two environment variables. I added the lib paths (the same ones that I added to `sys.path`) to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, i.e.:

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH":dba/sybase/ase/15.7/OCS-15_0/python/python26_64r/lib:/dba/sybase/ase/15.7/OCS-15_0/lib
```

and I had to change the `SYBASE` path from 12.5 to 15.7. All this was done in `csh`.

If I print conn.error(), after every curr.execute(), I get:

```
("Server message: number(5701) severity(10) state(2) line(0)\n\tChanged database context to 'master'.\n\n", 5701)
```

Comment: You can specify the database name in your select.  'select * from db_1..table_1'  I don't know if that will help, but it makes for more concise code.

Comment: The docs don't seem to require use db_1 ( http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01692.1570/doc/html/car1313098595988.html ). Try printing conn.messages() after every communication with database to see if there are any warnings/errors.

Comment: conn.messages() doesn't seem to be a function in the api, but if I print conn.error(), after every curr.execute(), I get:
("Server message: number(5701) severity(10) state(2) line(0)\n\tChanged database context to 'master'.\n\n", 5701)

Comment: As an aside, you might consider contacting Sybase technical support.  Their documentation seems to reference sample sample code, but never actually provides it over the web.   Sybase is not free, so I imagine that any sort of license will probably come with at least basic email support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely understand where you might be confused by the documentation.  Its doesn't seem to be on par with other db extensions (e.g. psycopg2).

When connecting with most standard db extensions you can specify a database.  Then, when you want to get the data back from a `SELECT` query, you either use fetch (an *ok* way to do it) or the iterator (the *more pythonic* way to do it).

```
import sybpydb as sybase

conn = sybase.connect(user='usr', password='pass', servername='serv')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("use db_1")
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table_1")
print "Query Returned %d row(s)" % cur.rowcount

for row in cur:
    print row

# Alternate less-pythonic way to read query results
# for row in cur.fetchall():
#    print row
```

Give that a try and let us know if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, this returns a "expected at most 3 arguments, got 4" error.

Comment: Removed the database keyword from call to connect.  Does that work?

Comment: "TypeError: 'sybpydb.Cursor' object is not iterable" and "Query Returned -1 rows(s)".

Comment: Did you try it with `cur.fetchall()`?

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.x working solution:

```
import sybpydb

try:
    conn = sybpydb.connect(dsn="Servername=serv;Username=usr;Password=pass")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute('select * from db_1..table_1')

    # table header
    header = tuple(col[0] for col in cur.description)
    print('\t'.join(header))
    print('-' * 60)

    res = cur.fetchall()

    for row in res:
        line = '\t'.join(str(col) for col in row)
        print(line)

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

except sybpydb.Error:
    for err in cur.connection.messages:
        print(f'Error {err[0]}, Value {err[1]}')
```